# Spring configuration via code vs. configuration via annotations

Tags: spring-annotations, applicationcontext, spring-bean, spring-config, springjunit4classrunner

I create Spring ApplicationContext via code like the following:

```
public static AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext startContext(String activeProfile,
                              PropertySource<?> propertySource, Class<?>... configs) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext result = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    if (propertySource != null) {
        result.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
    }
    if (activeProfile != null) {
        result.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(activeProfile);
    }
    result.register(configs);
    result.refresh();
    return result;
}
```

In test class I call it like that:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
class FunctionalTest {
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        appContext = Utils.startContext("functionalTest", getPropertySource(), 
                            BaseConfig.class, MyApplication.class, StorageTestConfig.class);
    }
}
```

It works fine, no problems.

Now I'm trying to do the same but via annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BaseConfig.class, MyApplication.class, StorageTestConfig.class}, 
                      loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@ActiveProfiles("functionalTest")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:test-context.properties")
class FunctionalTest {
      @Autowired
      private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
      ...
}
```

**And this doesn't work at all.** `applicationContext` is not autowired, beans from configurations too. Can you please say me that possibly I do wrong?

Why I want to switch from code to annotations: I want to be able to autowire beans from configs. Now (in code way of context creation) I should write something like `appContext.getBean("jdbcTemplate", JdbcTemplate.class)` in test methods. It will be great if I will be able to write

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

and this will work :)

Comment: Can you please post a stack trace with an exception thrown when you're trying to use annotations?

Comment: There is no exception was thrown, it is just not fill @Autowired fields (ApplicationContext and JdbcTemplate (bean from StorageTestConfig class)). They remain nulls

Comment: How do you run your tests? What is your version of JUnit?

Comment: Junit5, I run test in Idea Intellij IDE by click on run button

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using two versions of JUnit at the same time: JUnit 4 and JUnit 5.
(or use JUnit4 api and JUnit5 api the same time)

Where annotation `@Test` comes from in your `FunctionalTest`?

Is it `org.junit.Test`? Or is it `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`?

Seems it is from `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`.

Then you should use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class` instead of  `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BaseConfig.class, Utils.ServConfig.class, Utils.MvcConfig.class, MyApplication.class, StorageTestConfig.class}, 
                  loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@ActiveProfiles("functionalTest")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:test-context.properties")
class FunctionalTest {
      @Autowired
      private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

}
```

Note that `SpringExtension` is available since `5.0` version. If you're using lower version, you have to use JUnit4, mark test methods with `org.junit.Test`

> In test class I call it like that:
>   It works fine, no problems.

`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` is worthless here. You run this test using JUnit5. `@RunWith` not considered. But `@BeforeEach` is considered. Hence it's working.

In your `FunctionalTest` no annotations considered so it's not working. 
Use either JUnit4 (`@org.junit.Test`, `@RunWith`) or JUnit5 (`@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`, `@ExtendWith`).

> Seems you are using two versions of JUnit at the same time: JUnit 4 and JUnit 5.

If you're not migrating from JUnit4 to JUnit 5, consider using only one version of JUnit.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I changed RunWith on ExtendWith and it started to do something :)

Comment: But now it throws exception that I described in UPDATE part in my question.

Comment: I think using `ApplicationContext` rather than `AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext` in `Utils.ServConfig` would help.

Comment: It seems to me as design problem. You can hack it injecting `ApplicationContext` and casting it to any subclass of `ApplicationContext` you need where necessary. Please consider asking a new question because the problem we're discussing is going out of scope originally asked question